# Can sort() in C++ have a n^2 performance?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, gnu

When trying to estimated the performance of a program, I always treated sort() function as a worst-performance-n^2 function. However, I came across a Wikipedia page:

[sort(C++)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28C++%29)

Which states that the GNU C Library sort() uses some hybrid sorting algorithm called Introsort first, then do insertion sort. The corresponding page to Introsort claims that this algorithm has a worst case performance of nlogn. However, since I am not familiar with this algorithm, I still have the following worries about sort():

1) Can the hybrid algorithm used by GNU sort() guarantee a O(nlogn) performance? If so, how big can the constant overhead of the nlogn be?

2) Are there any other implementations that could cause sort() to perform worse than this (or better, which would be great)?

EDIT: Reply to Kevin: The sort() mentioned is std::sort().

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean std::sort or some other one?

Comment: Why would you assume `O(n^2)` performance?  It is easy to write a `O(n log n)` algorithm (ex. binary sort), so I would assume anyone writing a library function, for any language, could at least do that much.

Comment: @ BlueRaja: Just in case:) Even randomized quicksort can still have a teeny-weeny chance of being O(n^2), but I am not familiar about Introsort mentioned in my question.

Comment: Which page clames what? Introsort is O(n log n), the Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) states that clearly.

Comment: @Ziyao But then the universe implodes.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe: So just in order to ensure the safety of mankind (!!) I'd better try to understand the algorithm better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of quicksort and introsort (which is a variant of the former, with guaranteed `O(n log n)` performance achieved by switching to heapsort on worst case inputs) in place of other theoretically better algorithms like mergesort is due to the fact that the average case is the same, and the constants much lower (in the constants you can include the fact that it can be sorted in place, so there are no reallocations, and copies). And the worst case is bad, but quite improvable. In general, it is assumed that the performance of `sort` is `O( n log n )`.

If you are concerned about the hidden constants, then the question is not theoretical, but rather a question of performance. When trying to optimize you are better off *measuring* the algorithm on your actual data, analyzing the results of the measurement, and then determining where the time is spent and if it can be improved. But that is a completely different problem from the theoretical one.

Comment: Useful info, but the question is specifically about `std::sort()` in C++, and as Hostile Fork's answer points out there's actually no requirement that `std::sort()` use quicksort or introsort.  It would be good to make that clear.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I agree that it is more important to deal with *standard* c++ than with any particular implementation, but the question deals with one implementation: *the GNU C Library sort() uses some hybrid sorting algorithm called Introsort* [...] *Can the hybrid algorithm used by GNU sort() guarantee a O(nlogn) performance?* The answer tries to provide a rationale for that particular choice, and that if it *really* matters, you have to dig deeper than what the standard states. Maybe I should have used a different perspective... I have upvoted Hostile's answer, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: It's been pointed out that it depends on which version of GNU C++ Library you are using (note the "earlier versions" remark).  And I'd imagine that if down the line they came up w/a way to get a better average case, they'd sacrifice the worst case...citing the spec...

Comment: you're right -- I missed the fact that the GNU implementation was singled out. +1.

Answer (score 3):

If your standard library makes no guarantees beyond ISO 14882, then there seems to be no formal bound on the worst-case behavior of `sort()` — only the average complexity is listed.  There's a footnote in the standard which mentions you should use `stable_sort()` or `partial_sort()` instead of `sort()` if you care:

http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/lib-algorithms.html#lib.alg.sorting

> 25.3.1.1 - sort [lib.sort]
>
> ```
> template<class RandomAccessIterator>
> void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
>
> template<class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
> void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp)
> ```
>
> 1. Effects: Sorts the elements in the range [first, last).
> 2. Complexity: Approximately N log N (where N == last - first) comparisons on the average.*
>
> [Footnote: If the worst case behavior is important stable_sort() (lib.stable.sort) or partial_sort() (lib.partial.sort) should be used. --- end footnote]

Specific library implementations probably make stronger guarantees beyond the standard.  And it can certainly be useful to look at the code directly.  Then again, it depends on how portable you want this to be.

Comment: +1. Since the question is about `std::sort()` in C++ and not quicksort or introsort in general, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Seems I was a bit hasty and missed the fact that the question was mainly about GNU's implementation of `std::sort()`, so disregard the comment above...  Still a good answer though :)

Answer (score 2):

Introsort has actually O(n log(n)) worst-case running time, not O(n^2).
Also see [this remark](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html#2) at the SGI STL Specs:

> Earlier versions of sort used the
>   quicksort algorithm, using a pivot
>   chosen by median of three. Quicksort
>   has O(N log(N)) average complexity,
>   but quadratic worst-case complexity.
>   The current implementation of sort, however, uses the introsort
>   algorithm *whose
>   worst case complexity is O(N log(N))*.
>   Introsort is very similar to
>   median-of-three quicksort, and is at
>   least as fast as quicksort on average.

Comment: I find the comment "Introsort is very similar to median-of-3" quite odd. They use very different approaches to the problem. Also constructing difficult input for M3 is not hard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a variation of quicksort, using heapsort for suspected pathological quicksort input. It looks at recursion depth and when it falls too deep it sorts using heapsort removing any pathological behavior. This guarantees N log N.  The constant overhead of N log N (qsort vs heapsort) is not something to worry about.

Insertion sort is used when there are very few elements (about 16).

Comment: Actually the C++ standard doesn't specify what sorting algorithm `std::sort()` uses, only its average-case time complexity (see Hostile Fork's answer).

Comment: @j_random My impression was that the question certainly was about introsort and not std::sort specs.

Comment: Looking at the question again, you're right -- it's (mostly) about GNU implementation, which uses introsort. +1.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm lists several sorting algorithms with n^2 performance. It has one with n! performance. It also lists several non-comparison sorts which have performance based on other factors.

Comment: `2) Are there any other implementations that could cause sort() to perform worse than this (or better, which would be great)?` -- my reply addresses this aspect of the post... is my reply inaccurate or wrong for some other reason? I see no cause for down voting, and I'd like to understand why I was down voted if it's deserved.

Comment: Not a downvoter but I would suspect the downvotes came from not addressing OPs primary concern, 2 - can std::sort do worse than O(n²)